# Merge JSON in Python while keeping keys that are unique and overwrite common key

Tags: python

I have two JSON I need some way to merge the unique values and overwrite the common key with the later value. Ordering doesn't really matter as long as the content can be produced.

JSON 1

```
{ "key": {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "list": ["5", "6", "7"] } }
```

JSON 2

```
{ "key": {"b": "9", "list": ["8"] } }
```

Result JSON

```
{ "key": {"a": "1", "b": "9", "c": "3", "list": ["5", "6", "7", "8"] } }
```

Comment: Don't you need something recursive? Because it seems you don't always want to overwrite: if the value is a list, then the lists should be merged and not overwritten.

Comment: Do you have a specific question regarding your program? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to want to keep some values and overwrite others, I have hastily cobbled together a recursive function that does that, barring some edge-cases.

```
def combine(dict1, dict2):
    """Updates dict1 to contain dict2"""
    for key in dict2:
        if key in dict1:
            if isinstance(dict1[key], list): # If value is a list, we want special logic
                if isinstance(dict2[key], list): # if the "input" is a list, just do list + list
                    dict1[key] = dict1[key] + dict2[key]
                else:
                    dict1[key].append(dict2[key])
            elif isinstance(dict1[key], dict): # calling itself recursively
                dict1[key] = combine(dict1[key], dict2[key])
            else: # Overwrites all other values
                dict1[key] = dict2[key]
        else: # Creates the values that doesn't exist.
            dict1[key] = dict2[key]
    return dict1
```

It's a mess and nigh unreadable. Anyway, here is a demonstration:

```
import json
json1 = '{ "key": {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "list": ["5", "6", "7"] } }'
json2 = '{ "key": {"b": "9", "list": ["8"] } }'

json1 = json.loads(json1)
json2 = json.loads(json2)

print(json1) # {'key': {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'list': ['5', '6', '7']}}
print(json2) # {'key': {'b': '9', 'list': ['8']}}
print(combine(json1,json2)) # {'key': {'a': '1', 'b': '9', 'c': '3', 'list': ['5', '6', '7', '8']}}
```